# How to create a TTF or OTF font programmatically [C / C++]

Tags: c++, fonts

How do you go by creating a bitmap font with C or C++? I made some software that creates letterforms with your body and converts that to vector shapes (or bitmaps). I would like to output that result to a TTF, OTF or similar font file.

You can see a video of the software here:

http://vimeo.com/21396223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the specs for [OTF](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm) and [TTF](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/index.html). Also, there's an open source app for creating fonts called [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/), you can look at its implementation.

Comment: in the OTF spec you mentioned: "OpenType fonts may also contain bitmaps of glyphs, in addition to outlines. Hand-tuned bitmaps are especially useful in OpenType fonts for representing complex glyphs at very small sizes. If a bitmap for a particular size is provided in a font, it will be used by the system instead of the outline when rendering the glyph." - how do I go by creating a font file and putting these bitmaps in? any snippets?

Comment: Tried FontForge via scripting. The BitmapsAvail command appears to have a bug: http://osdir.com/ml/fonts.fontforge.devel/2007-06/msg00052.html This command seems to be required in order to generate bitmap fonts. Any ideas?

Comment: Used FontForge successfully (with some pain).